# App crashes on launch on one iPhone

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

It works fine on all other phones.

However, on one of my friends' phones, it doesn't even reach

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

So, what's the problem?

It works on all other phones. It used to work a few hours ago. Nothing has changed.

There is no error message or any message; it just crashes immediately on launch (opens to a black screen, and immediately exits back to the homescreen).

Comment: Attach the iPhone to your Macintosh and look at the console log of the device. And, I'm assuming you can't attach your friend's phone to your development machine, tell him to send you his console log (if he can figure out how to look at it).

Comment: Try deleting the app from his phone, removing all provisioning profiles for it, then recompiling and reinstalling.

Comment: give us the model of iphone you have tested it in and the model of your friend's phone.

Comment: I already deleted the app from his iPhone. Will remove provisioning profiles. The iPhone is iPhone 5. Other iPhone 5 works fine without issues. It could be the jailbreak. But before it works fine too on that phone.